# Write shell script to sort txt file contents?

Tags: operating-system

I have a file txt
for example:

watermelon
banana
orange
mango
apple

and the output that I want is:

apple
banana
mango
orange
watermelon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if your file is small or big as your question does not talk about that. If its a small file, you can use this approach -

```html
cat testFile | tr -s " " '\n' | sort
```